# How to cache my php menu

Tags: php, caching

Hello
I searched a bit here and didnt find anything for what i need...
I generate a css html menu from php every time a page is requested.However this menu is large... and when on remote server i can see each menu item drawing on the screen(every item is 3 level deep)...
So iam looking for an efficient way to cache the menu and dont have to generate it everytime..
I think generating a html page for the menu might be a solution but the problem is to know when it is updated and needs regeneration..

Comment: there is something wrong with your menu if you can see each menu item drawing on the screen (if it's about it's slowness). you have to optimize your menu, not cache it. **Why do you think it's because of generation at all?** Have you measured it? there are billion things involved - network, client, client-side programming, HTML rendering. How do you know it's just generation not anything else?

Comment: so you mean that there might be a problem? The menu code is evaled... You would draw the menu and not cache it?

Comment: what he is saying is that it depends where the bottleneck is. Only if you have identified the server-side process of building the menu itself (i.e. database accesses to find out the items, etc.) as the root of the problem, and can't be optimized any more, does caching make sense. If the 
*rendering in the browser* is what takes so much time, caching won't help you. You need to do some profiling to find out what exactly the issue is.

Comment: I should find where it is.. Localy it is ok but at remote server it gets slow... The menu is 50 kbytes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual point at which to trigger regeneration is (well, obviously) when the menu's data structure is changed.

It's impossible to give detailed advice without knowing what your application looks like, but you could, for example, add a mechanism to your back-end that deletes the cached version every time the user adds, removes or changes a menu item. The next time the page is opened, the cache gets re-built.

Alternatively, force a re-build of the cache directly in the menu interface... Whatever works best for what you're using.

Comment: should i do this or it is useless?

Comment: @Parhs impossible to tell! If your menu takes considerable time building, then yes, absolutely. But only you can find out for sure.